# Convert cx_oracle dataset/array to json using python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, cx-oracle

Using CX_ORACLE I am fetching data from oracle and using json.dumps() trying to convert into json format. But it's not properly happening and the json file create with list of arrays of data. Is there any way to convert to json other than writing a one to one map
Here is my snippet

```
            cursor = self.connection.cursor()
            coll = []
            headers = []
            cursor.arraysize = 10000
            cursor.execute(query)
            headers.append([x[0] for x in cursor.description])  # this will 
                  extract row headers
            while True:
                rs = cursor.fetchmany()
                if not rs:
                    print("no more rows")
                    break
                coll.append(rs)

            rs_list = [item for list in coll for item in list]
            rs_list = headers + rs_list
            result=json.dumps(rs_list)
            print(rs_list)
```

Comment: Can you clarify, by means of an example, what you think is "proper"? In other words, given a set of 2-3 simple rows, show what you expect to happen and what is actually happening.

Comment: Consider using some of the DB's JSON functionality: https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/json_data_type.html